# Import TBXML in xcode 4.3 for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, tbxml

I want to use the TBXML parser since I see it is a very fast one. In it's guide here http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides_-_Include_in_project.html at some place is says that

"4. Locate the Targets node in the group tree under your project. Click the arrow to expand and right click your project's target file. Select "Get Info" and navigate to the "General" tab.
4. Click the plus symbol at the bottom of the window to add a linked library. From the list, select "libz.dylib". You can now close this info window.
 "

I'm using xcode 4.3 and I can't see any Targets group. How do I add the linked library??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a reference to a library in xcode 4.3 you click on the Root of your project ( where you see your project's name on top left. Then click your project under "TARGETS" and go to tab Build Phases. And there you can add whatever you want.